# post parameters to asp web page through internet using Delphi

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, delphi

I made this code in Delphi

```
TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); var Response: TStringStream; Params: TStringList; 
 begin 
  Params := TStringList.Create; 
  try
   Params.Add('redirect=http://localhost:1645/default.aspx'); 
   Params.Add('long=' + edit1.Text); 
   Params.Add('lat=' + edit2.Text); 
   Response := TStringStream.Create(''); 
   try 
    IdHTTP1.AllowCookies := True; 
    IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;    
    IdHTTP1.Post('http://localhost:1645/default.aspx', Params, Response); 
    memo1.Text := Response.DataString; 
   except 
    on E: Exception do 
     begin 
      showmessage('Error: ' + E.Message); 
     end;
   end;  
  end;
 end;
```

To send parameters to an aspx page, when I run in VS and IIS the webapplication opens the browser, I enter manbually the parameters (it is long and lat for google maps) browser accepts the parameters and displays the map location, when I try to send with the above code browser doesn't do anything, any help to post parameters with delphi and Server executes the url with the params?

code c# asp

```
  public partial class YourFirstGoogleMap : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    public string v;
    public string c;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      v = Request.QueryString["long"];
      c = Request.QueryString["lat"]; 
    }
  }
```

and aspx

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
function InitializeMap() 
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%=v%>, <%=c%>);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),    myOptions);
 }
 window.onload = InitializeMap;
</script>`
```

How can I make javascript to listen for parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ASP C# code is expecting the parameters to be sent in a URL query string, but your Delphi code is sending them in a `POST` body instead.  The correct Delphi code would look more like this instead:

```
procedure TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    IdHTTP1.AllowCookies := True; 
    IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;    
    Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Get('http://localhost:1645/default.aspx?redirect=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode('http://localhost:1645/default.aspx') + '&long=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(edit1.Text) + '&lat=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(edit2.Text)); 
  except 
    on E: Exception do 
    begin 
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + E.Message); 
    end;
  end;
end;
```